# Implicitly define Dictionary pairs

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, variable-assignment

### Background

Defining an Array is typically demonstrated as `var array:Array = new Array()`, however, this relegates array assignment to methods like `array.push(value)` or linear declarations like ...

```
array[0] = "apple"
array[1] = "orange"
```

Obviously, a more succinct format is an implicit declaration, where a double bracket is understood to define an array, and the index is automatically handled.

```
var array:Array = ["apple", "orange"];
```

The same works for Objects...

```
var obj:Object = {
    "apple":"fritter",
    "orange":"pie"
}
```

---

### The Problem

The problem arises when trying to define a Dictionary's key:value pairs implicitly.  [Reading the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html#Dictionary%28%29), I was shocked to only find one method on the class.  The fact that it extends Object at least means `for ... in` are available, but that's about where the conveniences end.

Especially since we'll want to use weak keys, the one argument available to Dictionaries would need to be set to `true`, thereby precluding any kind of implicit definition.  The same documentation outlines typical usage in the former (lengthier) format I demonstrated with arrays:

```
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
dict[key] = "Letters";
```

That's just not going to fly for complicated structures.

*[ redacted `with` argument ]*

Because the docs for both Array & Object never actually explain implicit declarations, I can't help but imagine there might be a way to do so with Dictionaries.  Anyone know?

I'm thinking now my only option is to come up with some kind of method which maps a complex object tree to a dictionary... which is dumb, since it'd be faster to just use the long method first demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even if you write the code with `Object` and don't quote up strings as in original question, you'll not receive the expected results. And if you are attempting to use an object as a key in `with` statement, the compiler will be confused whether you want `dict[obj]` or just `obj` to be assigned a value. So, if you are adding a property to an `Object` or `Dictionary`, use the brackets syntax:

```
obj["apple"]="fritter";
dict[obj]="bar";
```

Etc.

Comment: You're correct.  `with` statements do not define declared variables inside the target object, but are simply local (consequently, I've redacted that portion of the question).  Still, there doesn't seem to be a more direct method of defining properties on a Dictionary.  `dict[obj]=value` feels like a serious step backwards compared to implicit declarations.

Comment: Otherwise you're getting a naming conflict, since `obj` is in the scope for `with` operator, so compiler will be confused if you are asking to make a `dict[obj]` entry in the dictionary or to assign `obj` another value.